# React.js show part of component on hover issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with showing an overlay over my component. Below is the code.

```
<div className="content">
    <div className="main" onMouseEnter={this.mouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeaves}>
    ...
    </div>
    <div className="overlay" style={this.getOverlayStyle()} ref="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the style method:

```
getOverlayStyle: function() {
    return {
        display: 'none',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0',
        bottom: '0',
        left: '0',
        right: '0',
        zIndex: '100'
    }; 
}
```

And these are the mouse event handlers:

```
mouseOver: function() {
    this.refs.overlay.style.display = 'block';
},
mouseLeaves: function() {
    this.refs.overlay.style.display = 'none';
},
```

Okay, so, when I hover over the content part, the overlay becomes visible, but it's flickering. When I stop moving the mouse above the content, the overlay is displaying nicely. When I move the mouse again, it flickers again, it's barely watchable, very annoying.

When I try making the overlay visible in the console (just your regular document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0].style.display = 'block', it works normally and doesn't flicker. I'm guessing this problem is due to my not yet great React knowledge.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Ps, I tried using a pure CSS solution: selector1 + selector2 { display: block; } and it behaved the same as above.

EDIT, I tried setting the visibility through state (change state on mouse enter and mouse leave), following a recommendation in the comments, but it still flickers when the mouse is moving.

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but if you are setting the style with React, you shouldn't change it by accessing the DOM.

Comment: It was the same when I was setting it with regular external CSS.

Comment: Is the overlay shown on top of the content? (i.e. the mouse will have entered the overlay?)

Comment: @KitFung the thought had crossed my mind, but I wondered if it was an overkill to change state "just for hover visibility", but yeah, that might be best. I'll go and do that now.

Comment: @KitFung nope, the flickering remains, despite setting it with state.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure I understand. The overlay has higher z-index value than the content and it is positioned absolutely, above all content.

Comment: You are just trying to show the overlay when the `main` is hovered, right?

Comment: *"it is positioned absolutely, above all content"* Because the overlay is not a child of the main element, that's the moment where the `mouseleave` is triggered. The mouse *leaves* the main element. That hides the overlay in which case the mouse *enters* the main element, which shows the overlay. The overlay should be child of the element you bind the handlers to.

Comment: `pointer-events: none`, would probably solve it but its not supported everywhere and it is also not the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to move the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to the `.content` div, not the `.main` div

what I expect is happening is this:

you enter main, the overlay is displayed which means the mouse leaves main and enters overlay. because it left main, the overlay is then hidden, and when the overlay is hidden, the mouse reenters main causing the cycle to rinse and repeat

although really this can be accomplished with css selectors. is there a reason you want to do this in react?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Such a clumsy error. I know I can do it in pure CSS, but I'm doing it in React to get to know it better.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pure css solution to this ([codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/yeNqNQ))

```
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  background-color: #0d0;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  zIndex: 100;
  background-color: #d00;
}
.content:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```